# JWT tokens and handlebars. Saving to localStorage

Tags: authentication, jwt, handlebars.js

I want to save a `JWT token` which is created in a log-in route. After the token is made I render the home page and want to pass the token with the render so that I can do `localStorage.setItem("token", {{token}})`. 
However, I don't know how to make the script tags work in a handlebars template. If someone could show me how this is done that'd be great.

Thank You.

Comment: i dont understand your first sentence on where the JWT came from? is it a server side variable or are you getting it from a client?

Comment: It is a server side variable. It is created if the login is successful, in a route on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t see the problem here.

server side:

```
res.render('homepage', { token: token });
```

client side:

```
<script>
  const token = "{{ token }}"
  // save it in localstorage
</script>
```

Comment: I have that script tag u have in my handlebars template but it doesn’t run when the template is rendered. Is there something that needs to be done to have a script tag in handlebars template? Thanks!